# Rose diagram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rose-plot

I want to draw a rose diagram of some circular data. I have been using the `circular` package and within this package it allows you to draw a simple rose diagram using the function: `rose.diag`. While this draws the diagram I want to be able to improve the plots but I can't find away to add to the plot or adjust it slightly. I have looked at drawing it in `ggplot2` but this doesn't seem clear to me and I am struggling to find another package in R which draws rose diagrams like this.

I post a sample of data and my current code below along with my queries:

```
Angle
0.65454759
0.01355458
0.5052027
0.2264302
-0.350552
-0.428481
0.1231778
0.258787
0.06723504
0.06906181
2.54608572
-1.6591672
3.00437314
-0.0503291
-0.828578
-1.9616418
-0.6468774
0.01438686
0.1162713
0.9938797
0.1861583
0.1547071
0.2577813
0.5110576
0.08714113
```

These data are radian turning angles. Using the `circular` package I make this data a vector of class `circular`:

```
x <- circular(Angle)
```

Then draw a rose diagram using the following code where it plots the diagram in degrees and not radians:

```
rose.diag(x, pch = 16, cex = 1, axes = TRUE, shrink = 1, col=3, prop = 2, 
    bins=36, upper=TRUE, ticks=TRUE, units="degrees")
```

There are 3 things I would like to add to this plot:

1. Change the plot orientation so that 0 is at the top and not on the right.
2. Add concentric circles to the plot to help with visual interpretation of the size and weight of each of the "bins".
3. Add a line to identify the mean angle (with sd error bars if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  There is a "zero" argument for `rose.diag` in this package.

```
y <- scan() # paste in the values from the question and hit return twice
y <- circlar(y) # not necessary but prevents a warning
rose.diag(y, units = 'degrees', zero = pi/2) # units doesn't change the underlying units
```

Alternatively you could have set properties of the `circular` object that you created.

```
y <- circlar(y, zero = pi/2)
rose.diag(y, units = 'degrees') # note, no 0 call here
```

So, now the plot is rotated... how to add stuff...

```
> par('usr')
[1] -1.376553  1.376553 -1.123200  1.123200
```

That gives me user coordinates and tells me the plot dimensions in user space.  Now I can do things like add a circle.

```
symbols(0, 0, circle = 0.2, inches = FALSE, add = TRUE, fg = 'red')
```

There is a `lines.circular` function but it wasn't obvious to me how to use it.  I could also plot a line using `segments` or `arrows` commands and draw right on the plot with them.  It requires a bit of euclidean geometry to convert an angle and length of the line to points.  This should all get you started.

```
m <- mean.circle(y)
segments(0, 0, cos(m+pi/2), sin(m+pi/2), col = 'red') # note I need to add the new 0 position... there is a lines.circular function but it wasn't obvious to me how to use it.
```

(tip... the framing circle in `rose.diag` is at a radius of 1 so giving that to the `circle` argument in `symbols` will draw exactly at that point)

Comment: That's great, thank you. I hadn't realised there was a 'zero' argument. There are two additional questions: Is it possible to draw the x and y axes (joining 0 to 180 and 90 to 270)? Also do you have any idea how I could add circular error bars to the mean line?

Comment: The segments command can draw any straight line.  You need to figure out an equation for your curve idea.  You decide the start and end points in terms of angles and then just calculate based on angle and radius a series of euclidean points.  So, if the angle goes from 2-3 then just calculate 20 points in that angle range.  Use segments to then draw all of the little lines.